# Why does binding a submit event with `$("#submitButton").submit(function(){})` not work?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events, form-submit

I’m trying to figure out why `$("#submitButton").submit(function() {});` is not working.

I have this `<form>`:

```html
<div class="card p-2">
  <form>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="inputPasswordAgain" class="sr-only">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="inputPasswordAgain" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your password again!" required>

      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">Submit Changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I’ve written this AJAX code in jQuery to pass values to the server.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitButton").click(function() {
      var data = {};
      var i;

      for (i = 0; i < $("#sessionQuantity").html(); i++) {
        data[i] = $("#" + i).val();
      }

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "updateViewing-helper.php",
        data: data,
        success: function() {}
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Everything works fine if I use `.click(function(){`…`})`, but this will call the `updateViewing-helper.php` without submitting the form with the `<input>` and `<button>` elements. This means the user can skip putting their password in, and just click the button.

I tried to use `.submit(function(){`…`})`, then use `e.preventDefault()`, then pass all values into AJAX, then call the `updateViewing-helper.php` via AJAX, then I can check for the password matching server-side.

But the `.submit` event is not working: there is not alert or anything.

Comment: Did you include the jQuery library in your code? It is not part of the browsers standard javascript core

Comment: submit-event is NOT for buttons, but for forms... give your FORM an ID and bind "submit" to it

Comment: `i < $("#sessionQuantity").html()` ????

Comment: or call the form submit() in your click event

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, the .click is working.

Comment: @ScottMarcus it will get the number of items in Session array, that part of the code works just fine, cause I set the ID of each selection dropdown from 0 to sessionQuantity -1 (cause each item in the session is one row with 1 dropdown) So i'll just pass in AJAX the data like 0: Dropdown value 1, 1: Dropdown value 2. Then use $_POST[0] or $_POST[1] in the php file to get the value and update the Session.

Comment: No, I mean you shouldn't be using `.html()` when the string in question doesn't contain any HTML. For non-HTML strings use `.text()`.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz even if I change the Buttion to Input, it's still not working, no pop up whatsoever. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @ScottMarcus oh, it just get the number for the loop. I have a <p id=sessionQuantity> somewhere above that count of item in the session.

Comment: submit is still an event for FORM...

Comment: Right, so don't use `.html()` for that, use `.text()`.

Comment: You are trying to use onSubmit() on a button which looks out of place. Try listening to the onSubmit event on the form element itself.

Answer (score 4):

Call submit on form not on the button

First give id to form

```
<form id="myForm">
```

Then call submit on this id

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#myForm").submit(function(){

    });
});
```

Comment: ahh here we go, thank you! I should use $("#of the form).submit. not $("of the button").submit. And it does not work for button tag even tho its type is submit!!

Comment: Updated: it also works with button tag as long as its type is "submit"