# My HTML document is refreshed when I submit the form

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

> My HTML document is refreshed when I submit the form. Is there any way to prevent this ??

> how to send data using Ajax without refreshing the page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#">
        <input type="text" name="" id="">
        <button type="submit">asdf</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $("button").submit(function (e) { 
          e.preventDefault();                
          var dataString = $("input").val();
          $.ajax({
              type: 'post',
              url: 'data.php', 
              data: { album: dataString},
              success: function(response) {
                  alert(response);
              }
          });
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want to prevent the default behavior of the form in your case. Since the default behevavior is submit, and the action is set to `#` it will simply refresh the current page.
Use the `preventDefault()` method. Googling the issue further should help you a great deal.

Comment: @user4642212 not quite sure what you mean. If you specify the type of the button to be a submit inside the form element, it'll do just that (submit). A button that does not have a type definition will automatically be interpreted as submit by the browser. Defining the type as something other than submit will change the functionality of the button.

Comment: @Martin I’m not talking about the `type` attribute, but about the event type. `<button>`s are not `submit` event targets, but `<form>`s are.

Comment: @Martin _“Use the `preventDefault()` method.”_ — they already do.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does binding a submit event with `$("#submitButton").submit(function(){})` not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55248006/4642212).

Answer (score 2):

You are attaching the event to the wrong HTML element. Forms have `onsubmit` events, buttons do not.

Replace your

```
$("button").submit(function (e) {
```

by (assuminng you add an ID of `form` to your form):

```
$("#form").submit(function (e) {
```